# Please show me how to load a second video using javascript

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api

I have the below code that works fine I just need to alter it so when the video ends it plays another can someone please show me how to do this I have no clue.

Tim

```
<script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '4L5g2kN9oUU',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {          
            alert('done');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer**
After the first video is finished it will check for a bool if false, it will set it to true and set youtube player to the new videoId after that it will execute the play function of the youtube player.

you have to change the secondvideoId to play the other video, it would not replay the first video, so dont forget.

```
var firstVId = '4L5g2kN9oUU';
var secondVId = '4L5g2kN9oUU';

var bPlayedSecondTime = false;


// create youtube player
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: firstVId,
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}

// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {          
        alert('done');

        if(bPlayedSecondTime == false)
        {
          player.loadVideoById(secondVId);
          bPlayedSecondTime = true;
          event.target.playVideo();

        }
    }
}
<script>
```

Comment: Tried that like this did not work   
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {          
       
     function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '200',
    width: '300',
    videoId: 'dQw4w9WgXcQ',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried redeclaring `player` with a new instance?

```
// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {          
        alert('done');
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: '[next video ID]',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: player.loadVideoById(videoId);